# sharepoint 2010 infopath custom code button hidden

Tags: visual-studio-2010, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, infopath

I've been giving a really fun task at work, 
I need to create a SharePoint app or some sort of list on sharepoint, where someone can nominee people from the company to win some sort of recognition then this will go out to a group of people that will approve if they "deserve the recognition".
this project was being work by a guy that left the company last Friday so basically I have a week to do something about it and I don't really know a lot about SharePoint.

I've done my research, and at first I went straight to the technical point of view where I would  just basically code a connection to database, design the interface etc... but  sharepoint has a really friendly user interface, uh, so friendly that sometimes I feel like I'm not capable of controlling it.

I was assigned a "technical" resource, this person supports SharePoint in the company however she doesn't have experience of creating custom applications or what else.

she teach me how to create a list and editing a form, adding columns to it. A easy way of doing it btw, the fields were connected to the internal database in the company so basically I didn't have to do anything technical at that point.

but then it came the complications/limitations for example I wasn't able to auto-fill information let's say if I would search the name of a person I would want to fill his last name, phone number organization automatically, I would also like to nominee more than 1 people for a single project.

I found out that you're able to open the form in InfoPath so I did it and then I was looking for developer tap option but it just disappear every time I open up the form.

I was also expecting for a tree view or a binding view of the internal database where some controls were connected but I wasn't able to find anything.

I can only use the SharePoint that's already up on the intranet of the company, I don't have access to databases, therefore I can't connect to them "directly" let's say from VStudio to map data back and forth.

I understand this may not be a very technical question this more of an advice to a fellow developer I develop generally for android.

is there a way of just going around this issue?

thanks and I appreciate whoever reads this.

David,

Answer (score 0):

I don't think someone is ever going to have an issue like this, but I came to the conclusion that you need access to the sharepoint server and use VS inside the server in order to code the custom list and form, having the capability to connect to internal databases.

Answer (score 0):

Please ask one question per post!

> I've done my research, and at first I went straight to the technical
>   point of view where I would just basically code a connection to
>   database, design the interface etc...

For this, you do not need to use Sharepoint! Use MS SQL Server

> she teach me how to create a list

If you have chosen to usу Sharepoint lists then they use нтвук the MS SQL Server for storing them...

> I found out that you're able to open the form in InfoPath so I did it
>   and then I was looking for developer tap option but it just disappear
>   every time I open up the form.

Please check [the answer to question "Custom Code is disabled on my form/(it is a workflow form of a sp list workflow process)/ any workaround?"](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/a/44168). That is, code behind is not available in Infopath for Sharepoint List Form, it is by design.